# Prevent implicit conversion in template-enforced method

Tags: c++, templates, interface, implicit-conversion

Suppose we have something like this:

```
template <class B>
class A
{
   void Foo(B& b)
   {
       b.Bar(0.5);
   }
};

class B
{
    void Bar(float) {}
    void Bar(double) {}
    void Bar(int) {}
};
```

In this code, type `B` must provide a method `Bar()` which takes an argument of some integral type. The problem is here all 3 versions of `B::Bar()` are allowed. Is there any way to only allow one version of these methods, for example, only compile if `B` provides `Bar(float)`?

Comment: Why does B itself has no template?

Comment: So, to get things straight, you want the check in A? And it seems to me you're asking for two different things - it's possible to check whether template argument `B` has got a method `Bar` that takes a float. But that itself won't prevent things like `b.Bar(0);`. Can you clarify?

Comment: You're passing in literal values to the `Bar` call, I don't see what you're trying to get the compiler to do for you that you can't do yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this (horrible) technique, which will cause compilation to fail if `A` is instantiated with a type `B` that doesn't have a public `void Foo(float)` member, by attempting to take a specific pointer-to-member type from it.

```
template <class B>
class A
{
public:
   void Foo(B& b)
   {
       static_cast<void (B::*)(float)>(&B::Bar);

       b.Bar(0.5);
   }
};
```

([Demo of a resulting compilation failure](http://ideone.com/0FeTcU).)

If you want to actually call this method though then you need to use `b.Bar(0.5f);`.  `0.5` is a `double` literal, not a `float` literal, so you would check to ensure that it has the right member but then if it has a `void Bar(double)` you would call that anyway.  Changing the constant to `0.5f` would fix this.

Note that since taking the pointer has no side-effects and the result is not used, any decent compiler will optimize this away as a no-op.

---

You can also go the traditional SFINAE route with something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename TMethod>
class has_bar_method
{
private:
    struct yes { char _; };
    struct no { char _[2]; };
    template <typename U, TMethod = &U::Bar>
    static yes impl(U*);
    static no impl(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(impl(static_cast<T*>(nullptr))) == sizeof(yes) };
};
```

Used like this:

```
void Foo(T& b)
{
    static_assert(has_bar_method<T, void (T::*)(float)>::value, 
                  "T has method void Bar(float)");

    b.Bar(0.5f);
}
```

Now if the template fails to instantiate, we get a nice message explaining why:

> prog.cpp:25:8: error: static assertion failed: T has method void Bar(float)

([Demo](http://ideone.com/bQFhfB))

Comment: Marked as answer. Can you comment on why your first suggestion is horrible?

Comment: @user1715925 By itself, the cast looks unnecessary and could be removed accidentally during future maintenance. Of course, you can guard against this by adding a comment explaining why it is there. However, the error message it produces is not very helpful. `static_assert` lets you specify a custom error message which is more likely to convey the problem clearly.

Comment: thanks, would you mind putting that in the answer? It might help others